# Touch Events not registering for HTML5 Canvas Authoring using Flash CC

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas, createjs

I have been having some issues when it comes to authoring HTML 5 Canvas in Flash CC, mostly as a result of the lack of information on writing JavaScript inside Flash.

I have been converting an existing drag and drop .fla into HTML 5 with the hope of making it iOS and Android compatible. It is already functioning with mouse, but I have hit a brick wall on trying to add touch support.

The only way I have been able to even register the touch events is by listening to the entire window, which isn't very useful when I have multiple pieces that I want to move around.

This is what I have so far, all this code is located on the first frame of the main Scene Timeline, and the scene is composed of 5 pieces and 5 targets for those pieces, as well as a pop up task completed box and a reset button.

```
this.stop();
MainStage = this;//Declare 

//*********************
//Actual Drag and Dropping

// Initialize:
var numPieces = 5;//<---------------Place number of pieces HERE---------------
var homePosX = [];
var homePosY = [];
var correctAns = 0;
var isClickableAry = [];
var whoAmI = [];//Declared "Globally" so that I can identify which piece is being grabbed later

for (var i = 0; i < numPieces; i++)
{
    var pieceName = "p" + (i + 1);
    var piece = this[pieceName];
    //This sets the starting position for each piece    
    homePosX[i+1] = piece.x;//(i+1) is so that Piece names line up with Target names and MC names
    homePosY[i+1] = piece.y;
    whoAmI[i] = piece;
    isClickableAry[i] = 1;//Makes it so each pieces is set as clickable



if( piece ){
    piece.name = pieceName;
    piece.on("mousedown" || "touchstart", function(evt)
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
//Debug
        console.log(checkPiece(this));
//Rather than adding and removing event listeners, just check to see if piece is clickable
    if(isClickableAry[checkPiece(this)] == 1){

        this.parent.addChild(this);// Bump to top
        this.offset = {x:this.x - evt.stageX, y:this.y - evt.stageY};
//Debug
        console.log(piece + "PICKED UP, X " + piece.x + ", Y " + piece.y + " is Clickable? ");
        //Set Home Coordinates (Where it was picked up)
        homeX = this.x;
        homeY = this.y;
    }
});
piece.on("touchmove",function(evt)
{

        console.log("touch moved! " + touchobj);

        evt.preventDefault();
});

piece.on("pressmove", function(evt)
{
    if(isClickableAry[checkPiece(this)] == 1){
        this.x = evt.stageX + this.offset.x;
        this.y = evt.stageY + this.offset.y;

        //Mouse Cursor change
        document.body.style.cursor='move';
    }
});
piece.on("pressup" || "touchend" || "touchcancel", function(evt)
{
    var target = this.parent["t"+this.name.substr(1)];
    //Reset Cursor
    document.body.style.cursor='auto';

    if( target && hitTestInRange( target, 60) && isClickableAry[checkPiece(this)] == 1 ){
        this.x = target.x;
        this.y = target.y;
        //If it is correct add one
        correctAns++;
        //Make that button Unclickable
        isClickableAry[checkPiece(this)] = 0;

        if(correctAns >= numPieces){

            //If they have answered correctly equal to the the number of pieces
            MainStage.complete_mc.parent.addChild(MainStage.complete_mc);//Bump to top
            MainStage.complete_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            //reset answer counter and make drag pieces and buttons unclickable
            correctAns = 0;
//Debug             
            console.log(correctAns + "CORRECT!";)
        }


        }else{
            //Return to home Coordinates (Where it was on intialization)
            if(isClickableAry[checkPiece(this)] == 1){
                this.x = homePosX[checkPiece(this)+1];
                this.y = homePosY[checkPiece(this)+1];
            }
        }
    });
    piece.on("mouseover", function(evt)
    {
        if(isClickableAry[checkPiece(this)] == 1){
            //Makes cursor a pointer finger
            document.body.style.cursor='pointer';
        }
    });

    piece.on('mouseout',function(evt)
    {
        //sets cursor back to normal
        document.body.style.cursor='auto';
    });

}
}
function hitTestInRange( target, range )
{
if( target.x > stage.mouseX - range &&
target.x < stage.mouseX + range &&
target.y > stage.mouseY - range &&
target.y < stage.mouseY + range )
{
return true;
}
return false;
}
//Check which piece it is
function checkPiece(checkName)
{
for (var i = 0; i < numPieces; i++)
{
    if (checkName == whoAmI[i]){
    return i;
    }
}
}


//Reset Functionality

this.complete_mc.reset_btn.addEventListener("click", resetPos.bind(this));

function resetPos(){
for (var i = 0; i < numPieces; i++)
    {
        var pieceName = "p" + (i + 1);
        var piece = this[pieceName];
        correctAns = 0;
        //Makes Pieces Grabable again
        isClickableAry[i] = 1;          
        //This returns each piece to their Original Starting Positions          
        piece.x = homePosX[i+1];
        piece.y = homePosY[i+1];
    }
}

//Controlling the Pop Up Window, window pops up when user answers everything correctly 
this.complete_mc.exitComplete_btn.addEventListener("click", closePopUp.bind(this));
this.complete_mc.exitComplete_btn_alt. addEventListener("click", closePopUp.bind(this));

function closePopUp(){
MainStage.complete_mc.gotoAndStop(0);
}
```

In my own troubleshooting with other problems that have come up generally the issue has to do with scope of either functions or variables, since when flash exports the files it generates its own .js file and turns all of your movie clips into code and separates the code that you have written by whichever frame you wrote it on.
Any help at all would be appreciated.

EDIT: After a bit more research I think the problem might have something to do with touch events only being able to target separate elements? So it isn't able to grab objects inside the canvas element just the canvas element itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that adding touch support is incredibly easy. All I was missing was one line of code
`createjs.Touch.enable(stage);`
this makes all the touch events respond as mouse events. and fixed all my issues.