# How to prevent Canvas to act like an Image on Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mobile

I have an interactive canvas, where you can click on some buttons. But when I test it on mobile, and try to click on the buttons, it doesnt react immediately. I have to press and wait for the action.

test here: http://choix.me/labor/canvas/car.html

here the javascript code for the upBtn:

```
    this.upBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", upClick.bind(this));
    this.upBtn.addEventListener("click", upRelease.bind(this));

    function upClick()
    {
                up = true;
                speed = 10;
                forward = 1;
    }
    function upRelease()
    {
                up = false;
                speed = 10;
                forward = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using mousedown and click events, neither of which are events that are naturally supported on a mobile browser.  They do work but not the same way they work on the desktop.  Tie into the touch events, specifically the touchstart and touchend event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

```
   this.upBtn.addEventListener("touchstart", upClick.bind(this));
    this.upBtn.addEventListener("touchend", upRelease.bind(this));

    function upClick()
    {
                up = true;
                speed = 10;
                forward = 1;
    }
    function upRelease()
    {
                up = false;
                speed = 10;
                forward = 0;
    }
```

not tested code, but the gist is there

Comment: Thx, No it has nothing to do with that. I mean yeah, you should use touch events, but the problem is, the canvas is an image and the mobile browser trys to make a "right click" when you touch an image longer than 300ms. That behavior is what I want to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

It had something to do with CreateJS:

This line fixes it:

```
    createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
```

from:
[Touch Events not registering for HTML5 Canvas Authoring using Flash CC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462406/touch-events-not-registering-for-html5-canvas-authoring-using-flash-cc)